# cannot use kubeadm init single kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am a newbie and are learning kubernetes，when i try to build kubernetes cluster, i meet some questions.
here's my questions, i don't know how to resolved it

When I enter the command：

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

I have encountered these problems：

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evtYv.png)

i tried to specified --apiserver-advertise-address=$(hostname - i), i meet another question:

```
$sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address 10.181.144.168
I0316 21:11:04.632624   37136 version.go:93] could not fetch a Kubernetes version from the internet: unable to get URL "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": Get https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt: dial tcp 23.236.58.218:443: connect: network is unreachable
I0316 21:11:04.632720   37136 version.go:94] falling back to the local client version: v1.12.2
[init] using Kubernetes version: v1.12.2
[preflight] running pre-flight checks
[preflight/images] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight/images] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight/images] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[kubelet] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[preflight] Activating the kubelet service
[certificates] Generated etcd/ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated etcd/peer certificate and key.
[certificates] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 localhost] and IPs [10.181.144.168 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certificates] Generated apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated etcd/server certificate and key.
[certificates] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 localhost] and IPs [127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certificates] Generated etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver certificate and key.
[certificates] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 10.181.144.168]
[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.
[certificates] valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf"
[controlplane] wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-apiserver to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[controlplane] wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-controller-manager to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[controlplane] wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-scheduler to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[etcd] Wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd instance to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
[init] waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[init] this might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled
d[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
d[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
d[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
dd[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI, e.g. docker.
Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
    - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'
couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
```

Most answers told me i need to access internet. But i've downloaded core images

```
$sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy                v1.12.2             15e9da1ca195        4 months ago        96.5MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver            v1.12.2             51a9c329b7c5        4 months ago        194MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.12.2             15548c720a70        4 months ago        164MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler            v1.12.2             d6d57c76136c        4 months ago        58.3MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                      3.2.24              3cab8e1b9802        5 months ago        220MB
k8s.gcr.io/coredns                   1.2.2               367cdc8433a4        6 months ago        39.2MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause                     3.1                 da86e6ba6ca1        15 months ago       742kB
```

And i find the log from /var/log/message:

```
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 systemd[1]: Starting kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent...
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes systemd probe.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 systemd[1]: Starting Kubernetes systemd probe.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.617395   81273 server.go:408] Version: v1.12.2
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.617559   81273 plugins.go:99] No cloud provider specified.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.620585   81273 certificate_store.go:131] Loading cert/key pair from "/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem".
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.654038   81273 server.go:667] --cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.654274   81273 container_manager_linux.go:247] container manager verified user specified cgroup-root exists: []
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.654289   81273 container_manager_linux.go:252] Creating Container Manager object based on Node Config: {RuntimeCgroupsName: SystemCgroupsName: KubeletCgroupsName: ContainerRuntime:docker CgroupsPerQOS:true CgroupRoot:/ CgroupDriver:cgroupfs KubeletRootDir:/var/lib/kubelet ProtectKernelDefaults:false NodeAllocatableConfig:{KubeReservedCgroupName: SystemReservedCgroupName: EnforceNodeAllocatable:map[pods:{}] KubeReserved:map[] SystemReserved:map[] HardEvictionThresholds:[{Signal:imagefs.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.15} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:memory.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:100Mi Percentage:0} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:nodefs.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.1} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:nodefs.inodesFree Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.05} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>}]} QOSReserved:map[] ExperimentalCPUManagerPolicy:none ExperimentalCPUManagerReconcilePeriod:10s ExperimentalPodPidsLimit:-1 EnforceCPULimits:true CPUCFSQuotaPeriod:100ms}
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.654396   81273 container_manager_linux.go:271] Creating device plugin manager: true
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.654432   81273 state_mem.go:36] [cpumanager] initializing new in-memory state store
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.654579   81273 state_mem.go:84] [cpumanager] updated default cpuset: ""
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.654599   81273 state_mem.go:92] [cpumanager] updated cpuset assignments: "map[]"
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.654695   81273 kubelet.go:279] Adding pod path: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.654745   81273 kubelet.go:304] Watching apiserver
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: E0318 10:48:39.655393   81273 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:442: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.181.144.168:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.181.144.168:6443: connect: connection refused
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: E0318 10:48:39.655393   81273 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.181.144.168:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dvsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.181.144.168:6443: connect: connection refused
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: E0318 10:48:39.655490   81273 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://10.181.144.168:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dvsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.181.144.168:6443: connect: connection refused
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.656470   81273 client.go:75] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.656489   81273 client.go:104] Start docker client with request timeout=2m0s
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.657494   81273 docker_service.go:540] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but kubenet is not enabled, falling back to "hairpin-veth"
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.657515   81273 docker_service.go:236] Hairpin mode set to "hairpin-veth"
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.657592   81273 cni.go:188] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.659005   81273 hostport_manager.go:68] The binary conntrack is not installed, this can cause failures in network connection cleanup.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.659058   81273 cni.go:188] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.659091   81273 docker_service.go:251] Docker cri networking managed by cni
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.671559   81273 docker_service.go:256] Docker Info: &{ID:FGTF:A4SR:ARMW:4TII:2HCM:CT3G:NYZA:XRMB:CSHA:E5X6:TWCE:5JIP Containers:0 ContainersRunning:0 ContainersPaused:0 ContainersStopped:0 Images:8 Driver:overlay DriverStatus:[[Backing Filesystem extfs] [Supports d_type true]] SystemStatus:[] Plugins:{Volume:[local] Network:[bridge host macvlan null overlay] Authorization:[] Log:[awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog]} MemoryLimit:true SwapLimit:true KernelMemory:true CPUCfsPeriod:true CPUCfsQuota:true CPUShares:true CPUSet:true IPv4Forwarding:true BridgeNfIptables:true BridgeNfIP6tables:true Debug:false NFd:18 OomKillDisable:true NGoroutines:26 SystemTime:2019-03-18T10:48:39.661768258+08:00 LoggingDriver:json-file CgroupDriver:cgroupfs NEventsListener:0 KernelVersion:3.10.0-327.ali2018.alios7.x86_64 OperatingSystem:Alibaba Group Enterprise Linux Server 7.2 (Paladin) OSType:linux Architecture:x86_64 IndexServerAddress:https://index.docker.io/v1/ RegistryConfig:0xc420925f10 NCPU:32 MemTotal:134992273408 GenericResources:[] DockerRootDir:/var/lib/docker HTTPProxy: HTTPSProxy: NoProxy: Name:vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 Labels:[] ExperimentalBuild:false ServerVersion:17.06.2-ce ClusterStore: ClusterAdvertise: Runtimes:map[runc:{Path:docker-runc Args:[]}] DefaultRuntime:runc Swarm:{NodeID: NodeAddr: LocalNodeState:inactive ControlAvailable:false Error: RemoteManagers:[] Nodes:0 Managers:0 Cluster:<nil>} LiveRestoreEnabled:false Isolation: InitBinary:docker-init ContainerdCommit:{ID:6e23458c129b551d5c9871e5174f6b1b7f6d1170 Expected:6e23458c129b551d5c9871e5174f6b1b7f6d1170} RuncCommit:{ID:b0917904e049873e6fe70520b9a049b8cb3a9ea2 Expected:b0917904e049873e6fe70520b9a049b8cb3a9ea2} InitCommit:{ID:949e6fa Expected:949e6fa} SecurityOptions:[name=seccomp,profile=default]}
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.671630   81273 docker_service.go:269] Setting cgroupDriver to cgroupfs
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.685561   81273 kuberuntime_manager.go:197] Container runtime docker initialized, version: 17.06.2-ce, apiVersion: 1.30.0
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.688250   81273 server.go:1013] Started kubelet
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: E0318 10:48:39.688286   81273 kubelet.go:1287] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.688306   81273 server.go:133] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: E0318 10:48:39.688620   81273 event.go:212] Unable to write event: 'Post https://10.181.144.168:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events: dial tcp 10.181.144.168:6443: connect: connection refused' (may retry after sleeping)
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.688664   81273 fs_resource_analyzer.go:66] Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.688694   81273 status_manager.go:152] Starting to sync pod status with apiserver
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.688707   81273 kubelet.go:1804] Starting kubelet main sync loop.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.688726   81273 kubelet.go:1821] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down PLEG is not healthy: pleg was last seen active 2562047h47m16.854775807s ago; threshold is 3m0s]
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.688746   81273 volume_manager.go:248] Starting Kubelet Volume Manager
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.688770   81273 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:130] Desired state populator starts to run
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.689076   81273 server.go:318] Adding debug handlers to kubelet server.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.689461   81273 cni.go:188] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: E0318 10:48:39.689645   81273 kubelet.go:2167] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.709949   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.750913   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/agent": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/agent/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.764355   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/crond.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/crond.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.764979   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/staragentctl.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/staragentctl.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.765499   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/systemd-journal-catalog-update.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/systemd-journal-catalog-update.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.766343   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/systemd-remount-fs.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/systemd-remount-fs.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.766793   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/docker.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/docker.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.766966   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/z_nic_irq_set.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/z_nic_irq_set.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.767171   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/syslog-ng.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/syslog-ng.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.767481   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/systemd-fsck-root.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/systemd-fsck-root.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.768221   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/systemd-update-utmp.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/systemd-update-utmp.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.768707   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/agent/logagent": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/agent/logagent/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.769014   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/ntpdate.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/ntpdate.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.769153   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/mcelog.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/mcelog.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: W0318 10:48:39.769860   81273 container.go:507] Failed to update stats for container "/system.slice/rhel-domainname.service": failure - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset,cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/rhel-domainname.service/cpuacct.stat is expected to have 4 fields, continuing to push stats
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.788819   81273 kubelet.go:1821] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down]
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: E0318 10:48:39.788824   81273 kubelet.go:2236] node "vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2" not found
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.788842   81273 kubelet_node_status.go:276] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.791263   81273 kubelet_node_status.go:70] Attempting to register node vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: E0318 10:48:39.791612   81273 kubelet_node_status.go:92] Unable to register node "vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2" with API server: Post https://10.181.144.168:6443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 10.181.144.168:6443: connect: connection refused
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.847902   81273 kubelet_node_status.go:276] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.849675   81273 cpu_manager.go:155] [cpumanager] starting with none policy
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.849686   81273 cpu_manager.go:156] [cpumanager] reconciling every 10s
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: I0318 10:48:39.849695   81273 policy_none.go:42] [cpumanager] none policy: Start
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 kubelet[81273]: F0318 10:48:39.849713   81273 kubelet.go:1359] Failed to start ContainerManager failed to get rootfs info: unable to find data in memory cache
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Mar 18 10:48:39 vsearchtradeg1host010181144168.et2 systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
```

I look forward to someone who can help me answer!

Comment: Is your machine connected to the internet? It seems as if it can't fetch a kubernetes distribution.

Comment: check if required ports are opened on the master node as per the documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/#master-node-s

Answer (score 1):

Did you have any cluster running prior to this? If so, you have to clean up old configs and re-bootstrap your cluster.

1. Reset current cluster- `kubeadm reset -f`
2. Delete obsolete config (entire directory) - `sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/`
3. Pull images once again - `kubeadm config images pull`
4. Pass bridged IPv4 traffic to iptables chains. This is a requirement for some CNI plugins to work
   `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1`
5. Init the cluster - `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`

Comment: when i execute 'sudo systemctl restart kubelet' , it can't works

Comment: @Alex what does it say? can you please share the output?

Comment: I find the print log, it shows:  failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory

Comment: @Alex This file is created during `kubeadm init` command.  As per your logs - `[kubelet] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"` it should be in place once init command complete successfully.  Did you try to remove **/etc/kubernetes/*.conf** ?

Comment: But my current situation is unable to initialize, you can see the detail from my question again

Comment: @Alex yes and I've suggested to clean up etc/kubernetes/ and try once again.

Comment: I am very sorry, I have tried it many times and it's can't works

Comment: @Alex still trying to reproduce your case. I have update my answer with one more step: **Pass bridged IPv4 traffic to iptables chains. This is a requirement for some CNI plugins to work** `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1`

Answer (score 0):

You should pass  - - apiserver-advertise-address=$(hostname - i) in init command

Comment: I re-edited my question, could you look at the problem for me again?

Comment: It appears like you are in a closed network. You need internet access on that machine

Comment: I've downloaded kubernetes. I can't understand why I need to link to the Internet.

Comment: During g cluster setup core images like api server, controller, scheduler, etcd, kube-proxy etc get downloaded for which you need internet access

Comment: @P Ekambaram But i've downloaded core images, includes  api server, controller, scheduler, etcd, kube-proxy and so on

Comment: You can look at my re-edited question again. I think it not seems like i need internet access, because i've downloaded the core images

Comment: kubelet appears to be down. can you can status of firewalld service and disable it is running

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch the command that you posted. you launched a command with the - - apiserver-advertise-address specified. But I think as pointed in the comments you dont have access to the internet, or are behind a proxy or firewall blocking internet access.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I'm a beginner. What is the principle of access to the internet when kubernetes init?

Comment: No worries Alex. Basically kube-adm tries to use the internet while installing. It use it to download packages and images. Try to use kubeadm config images pull to test the internet. Are you using kube-adm on your machine or in the cloud?

Comment: I'm using  kubeadm in my machine, Because of network reasons, I've downloaded the core images like api server, controller through my private repository in my first step.

Comment: Looks like kubeadm is ignoring your local images and reaching the remote docker repositories. Does the command kubeadm config images pull work?

Comment: when i execute 'kubeadm config images pull', it can't works. Because of network reason, I can't access https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/ to pull images

Comment: Some people are having same problem in this thread: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54188 . Basically try to lauch using the flag --kubernetes-version=v1.12.0 . Remember to launch a kubeadm reset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the kubernetes version during init to remove the error regarding not being able to connect to the internet:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --kubernetes-version=1.12.2 --apiserver-advertise-address=$(hostname -i)
```

This should work. If the `hostname -i` doesn't work, you need to use your ip address of your machine via an `ifconfig` or `ip list` command.

Answer (score 0):

try with this flag  --image-repository  and run init